# How do I add a picture background on tkinter on a toplevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I found this code for a picture background which worked great on my main window:

```
C = Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\file_address\\background.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

C.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=3)
```

However, when I used it on a Toplevel() window it didn't show up at all - I was left with a grey background. The only way it would show was when I used C.pack() but then all my widgets didn't show up. I tried playing around with C.lift() and C.lower() but none seem to work how I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It being garbage collected have reference to the image

```
C = Canvas(window, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\file_address\\background.png")
background_label = Label(window, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

background_label.image = filename # reference to the image
C.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=3)
```

doing that will let image display when you open the `toplevel window`